# make a new widget and use in a form

Tags: qt, widget

I'm new to the Qt Framework and Qt Creator, and I need to make a new widget with a UI contains some pushButtons, Labels, functions, and events and **then use it in another `form.ui`.**
or come to **Qt desiner toolbox** as custom widget.
**in C# i use UserControl.**
How can I do that?

i found `promote to` option but this is not my answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is already documentation on [how to create a Qt Designer custom widget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html). To be honest though, and this is a personal opinion, it is not really worth the effort unless this custom widget is extremely important to visualize in your UI layout.

You can just as easily create a placeholder widget or an empty layout for it in one UI design, and then add it to the layout in code later. The process is just simply:

1. Create custom widget as one UI
2. Create main UI with a an empty layout in the spot meant for custom widget
3. In code, `addWidget` to layout

Again, if you really need to visualize this custom widget in Designer, check out the docs. My perspective comes from a PyQt background where we use the Designer very very minimally just for complex layout design and do most of everything back in code anyways.

Comment: Instead of using empty layout I am using `promote to` option, which is not an answer.

Comment: thanx, your answer is very useful, but my problem is working in complex layout and multiple use from some different widgets

Comment: Yes and thats why I gave a link to the docs on how to create a designer plugin to make your widget available. The rest of the answer was just another option. Is the doc link no good?